# How do I hide events in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Sometimes I will be invited to an event that I don't care about. In these cases, I would like to hide the event from my event list. In some older version of the site, I could do this. I just can't find a way to manage this with the current (as of 7/7/2010) version.

I don't see a link under the image for an event.

Comment: I do not know if you are joking or not but you cannot remove your self from an event you were not invited to. This is the only way you will get the image above. If I am wrong you need to get through to facebook support.

Comment: This event only appears in my list on occasion. I just noticed the Remove From My Events link on other events that are more consistent. I think that this is a bug with open events, or something.

Comment: ok send the bug as an abuse since its taking away your choice to remove the event which may lead to  messages from the event owner to `abuse@facebook.com` maybe they will get on it right away

Comment: @EndangeredMassa: Your image is broken.

Comment: It loads for me.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: This answer has changed due to Facebook Events changing.

1. Click "Events" on the left menu.
2. Click "Invites" up at the top. (Should show a number indicating how many pending invites you have.)
3. Hover over the event in question and a blue "X" should appear in the right corner of the event listing.
4. Click the blue "X". :)

Comment: This solution allows you to continue to receive events from the creator in the future.

Comment: I don't see any links or hover effects on the events page under or near the event photos.

Comment: I've uploaded a photo describing what I see on my events in Facebook.

Comment: There is no link there, for me.

Comment: @Michael: Your image is broken.

Comment: Removed image and updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Select `Events` on the side while on the main page.

[image]

Select `Respond`

[image]

and at the bottom of the hover there is an option to remove the event.
This should stop future messages from the event creator as well.
[image]

Comment: Where does that list of buttons show up? In the main feed?

Comment: This is from the homepage to the event page. I placed in pretty pictures to guide you.

Comment: I don't see any of that on my events list. Thanks for the detailed answer, though.