# How can I prevent/lessen event spam on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention, facebook-events

On Facebook, you can be invited to an event by any of your friends. Once you have been invited to an event, the admins of that event can send messages straight to your inbox even if you have not sent an RSVP to that event. My problem with this system is that it essentially forces you to opt out of events rather than opt in. I shouldn't have to say I'm not going to a spammy event about some club night in order to not receive their advertisements. They should not be able to message me until I have accepted their invitation.

Is it possible to set this up? If not, are there any other steps I can take to lessen event spam?

Comment: This might interest you (if that privacy setting trick indeed works): http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/block-event-invitations-from-a-specific-person-on-facebook

Comment: @Jonik Thanks for your help Jonik. I tried this out and unfortunately it does not work. If you wish to display your events on your profile, the privacy setting allows you to hide the information from particular people. It is not prevent people from inviting you to events or messaging you once you are invited.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would've thought, but since that answer was accepted... Thanks for straightening it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is infuriating, and there is no solution to it, other than taking all of the time-consuming steps mentioned above.

I have just created the following page to try and get something done about it. Please Join.

http://on.fb.me/eventspam

Comment: Joined and will try and spread this as much as possible!

Comment: Here it is 2014, the problem still persists, and that Facebook page appears to no longer exist. [EDIT Actually it's in a very unfamiliar language.]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I look at it.

**Notications**

By default (I think), you would get an event notification in your mail.
This should be in the section "invites you to an event" here http://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?notifications
This is the point where you want to take action. Click on the event and then [remove](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/how-do-i-hide-events-in-facebook) the event. Now if you are using gmail and worried about lots of event invitation spam coming to your mail, set up a filter to mark it as read. (The first method can just be a way to remind yourself whether or not you want to attend the event.)

**Groups**

Stay away from these. Unless you are really dedicated in hearing what people in the group have to say. You should unsubscribe from the group. Go to the "Groups" section and start flushing all. Think to yourself ,"What value does this group give to me ?"
Groups such as the following should immediately be removed from your list.

- (*) Entertainment
- (*) Guest lists
- (*) Personal Photography/Design Freelancers

To me at least, these were the groups that spammed me the most.

**Privacy**

There is no privacy control for this. There is a privacy to control event box/tab visibility. That is about it. It seems the way this works is that acceptong friendship with someone allows them that privilege to invite you to an event. There is no privacy damage imparted by this (other than message spam). No one sees who is invited in the news feed. Once they accept an event invitation only then can one see who has not responded as yet.

**Last Resort**

For me, there is a small minority that creates the majority of spam. This is where the person ignores your messages/not part of a group and you are just tired of it. This assumes that you accepted based on "my friend is your friend too so why not". If you do not talk to the person regularly,watch their posts/photos nor write on their wall then the value of having that one extra person on your friends count is not worth it. [Remove](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3497/how-do-i-delete-friends-on-facebook) them as a friend.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, there isn't unless you RSVP No or select the "Remove from my Events" option.

Comment: This is my understanding too. Of course there are other ways to reduce "event spam": if a particular friend spams you a lot with uninteresting invites, ask him/her not to do that. If invites come from a group you belong to, leave the group. Etc.